# Automatically group elements by date

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an array including logs with a timestamp:

```
[
  {date: "Sat, 12 May 2018 13:54:23 GMT"}
  {date: "Sat, 12 May 2018 17:54:23 GMT"}
  {date: "Sat, 30 May 2018 13:54:23 GMT"}
]
```

My goal is to plot it into a chart so you can see how many entries are made (x axis is the time and y axis the number of logs). I tried to group my array and then plot it with chart.js, but the complexity of the algorithm grows when the time period is longer:

```
const date = moment(block.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
let id = myLineChart.data.labels.indexOf(date);
if (id < 0) {
    myLineChart.data.labels.push(date);
    id = myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.length;
    myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
        x: date,
        y: 0
    });
}
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[id].y++;
```

So I wanted to ask if there is a library that is doing this full automatically where you only pass date objects and maybe a time period and it groups the elements automatically.

Comment: @LGSon I need a special solution for date objects. For example if I a period of one day grouping by hours would be useful, but over one year months would be better.

Comment: This might be overkill but have you thought about making the solution 'dynamic'? Have a drop down for sorting so the user can pick hours, days, weeks, months, years and do the sort? Then you just have to redraw the chart which you would be doing anyway.

Comment: @LGSon I know a sort function is needed..and you gave mimo one. But mimo then said it has to be useful for different time factors (if chart based off day then hours...if based off a week then days...etc.) So taking your answer...adding my answer...you have a solution that involves a sort (your answer) with a way to sort by hours, days, etc (my answer). Never said mimo didn't need a sort.